# R - number of unique values in a column of data frame

Tags: r

for a dataframe `df`, I need to find the unique values for `some_col`. Tried the following

`length(unique(df["some_col"]))`

but this is not giving the expected results. However `length(unique(some_vector))` works on a vector and gives the expected results.

Some preceding steps while the df is created

```
df <- read.csv(file, header=T)
typeof(df) #=> "list"
typeof(unique(df["some_col"])) #=> "list"
length(unique(df["some_col"])) #=> 1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try with `[[` instead of `[`. `[` returns a `list` (a `data.frame` in fact), `[[` returns a `vector`.

```
df <- data.frame( some_col = c(1,2,3,4),
                  another_col = c(4,5,6,7) )

length(unique(df[["some_col"]]))
#[1] 4

class( df[["some_col"]] )
[1] "numeric"

class( df["some_col"] )
[1] "data.frame"
```

You're getting a value of 1 because the `list` is of length 1 (1 column), even though that 1 element contains several values.

Answer (score 10):

you need to use

```
length(unique(unlist(df[c("some_col")])))
```

When you call column by df[c("some_col")] or by df["some_col"] ; it pulls it as a list. Unlist will convert it into the vector and you can work easily with it. When you call column by df$some_col .. it pulls the data column as vector

Comment: Everyone here will appreciate a genuine help rather than a smartass response. It is unnecessary. Flagging it

Comment: Sorry for offending you. I just wanted to point out you use the word **need**, when you don't *need* (of course you *can*) to use `unlist()` (and I think it is a poor choice) when `[[` is available.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might just be missing a `,` 
Try

```
length(unique(df[,"some_col"]))
```

In response to comment :

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(A=c(1:10),B=rep(c("A","B"),5)))
df["B"]
```

Output :

```
B
1  A
2  B
3  A
4  B
5  A
6  B
7  A
8  B
9  A
10 B
```

and

```
length(unique(df[,"B"]))
```

Output:

```
[1] 1
```

Which is the same incorrect/undesirable output as the OP posted

**HOWEVER With a comma** `,`

```
df[,"B"]
```

Output :

```
 [1] A B A B A B A B A B
Levels: A B
```

and

```
length(unique(df[,"B"]))
```

Now gives you the correct/desired output by the OP. Which in this example is 2

```
[1] 2
```

The reason is that `df["some_col"]` calls a `data.frame` and `length` call to an object class `data.frame` counts the number of data.frames in that object which is 1, while `df[,"some_col"]` returns a `vector` and `length` call to a `vector` correctly returns the number of elements in that vector. So you see a comma (`,`) makes all the difference.

Comment: df["column name"] is same as [, "column name"]

Comment: actually not exactly the same, and the difference is enough to make it work. Added test to illustrate my point

Comment: The reason is that `df["column name"]` is a `data.frame` and `length` call to an object class `data.frame` counts the number of data.frames which is 1, while `df[,"column name"]` returns a vector and `length` call to a vector correctly returns the number of elements in that vector

Comment: thanx for clarification :)

Answer (score 2):

using tidyverse

```
df %>% 
  select("some_col") %>% 
  n_distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

The data.table package contains the convenient shorthand **uniqueN**. From the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)

*uniqueN is equivalent to length(unique(x)) when x is anatomic vector, and nrow(unique(x)) when x is a data.frame or data.table. The number of unique rows are computed directly without materialising the intermediate unique data.table and is therefore faster and memory efficient.*

You can use it with a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(some_col = c(1,2,3,4),
                 another_col = c(4,5,6,7) )
data.table::uniqueN(df[['some_col']])

[1] 4
```

or if you already have a data.table

```
dt <- setDT(df)
dt[,uniqueN(some_col)]

[1] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
df %>% 
distinct(column_name) %>% 
count()
```

or this without tidyverse:

```
count(distinct(df, column_name))
```

checking benchmarks in the web you will see that distinct() is fast.