# checking if dataframe has over 2 unique values in a loop in R

Tags: r

I have the following df:

```
## Load vcd package
library(vcd)

## Load Arthritis dataset (data frame)
data(Arthritis)

Arthritis <- Arthritis[,2:5]

head(Arthritis)

  Treatment  Sex Age Improved
1   Treated Male  27     Some
2   Treated Male  29     None
3   Treated Male  30     None
4   Treated Male  32   Marked
5   Treated Male  46   Marked
6   Treated Male  58   Marked
```

I want to look through the column names then check if if the unique values in each column is over 2 or not. how can i do this?
commented code is just pseudo code

```
for (n in colnames(sim_df)) {
     # if unique_vals(n) > 2 then..
 
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41906878/r-number-of-unique-values-in-a-column-of-data-frame plus use it with an apply function - `sapply(mtcars, \(x) length(unique(x)) > 2)`

Comment: This is awesome, but how do i make this into a boolean statement. Essentially " IF column is over length 2 then do this".

Comment: something like this - `lapply(mtcars, \(x) if(length(unique(x)) > 2) x else "something")`

Answer (score 1):

With a `for` loop completing your pseudocode.

```
for(col in colnames(data)) {
  if(length(unique(data[[col]])) > 2) {
    #do something 
    print('1')
  } else {
    #do something else
    print('0')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Library

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Data

```
df <- 
structure(list(Treatment = c("Treated", "Treated", "Treated", 
"Treated", "Treated", "Treated"), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male"), Age = c(27L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 46L, 58L
), Improved = c("Some", "None", "None", "Marked", "Marked", "Marked"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

## Check unique values per variables

### Code

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.character),n_distinct)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),names_to = "variable",values_to = "unique_values")
```

### Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  variable  unique_values
  <chr>             <int>
1 Treatment             1
2 Sex                   1
3 Improved              3
```

## Apply condition to variables with more than 2 unique values

In the example below, when a variable has more than 2 unique values, the function `str_to_upper` will be applied, `str_to_lower` otherwise.

### Code

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = where(is.character),
                .fns = function(x) if(n_distinct(x) > 2){str_to_upper(x)}else{str_to_lower(x)} ))
```

### Output

```
 Treatment  Sex Age Improved
1   treated male  27     SOME
2   treated male  29     NONE
3   treated male  30     NONE
4   treated male  32   MARKED
5   treated male  46   MARKED
6   treated male  58   MARKED
```

Comment: This is awesome, but how do i make this into a boolean statement. Essentially " IF column is over length 2 then do this".

Answer (score -1):

`for` loop style could be done like

```
for (i in colnames(dummy)) {
  if (dim(unique(dummy[i]))[1] > 2){
    print(i) # do something
  } else {
    #do something
  }
}

[1] "Age"
[1] "Improved"
```